# How to Grep nmap output?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I have a massive `scan.gnmap` file:

```
Host: 1.1.1.1 ()    Status: Up
Host: 1.1.1.1 ()    Ports: 80/open/tcp//http//nginx/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//nginx/    Ignored State: filtered (4998)
Host: 2.2.2.2 (foo.com) Status: Up
Host: 2.2.2.2 (foo.com) Ports: 80/open/tcp//http//awselb|2.0/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//Apache httpd 2.4.41 (() PHP|5.3.29)/ Ignored State: filtered (4998)
Host: 3.3.3.3 (bar.com) Status: Up
Host: 3.3.3.3 (bar.com) Ports: 25/open/tcp//smtp?///    Ignored State: filtered (4999)
Host: 4.4.4.4 ()    Status: Up
Host: 4.4.4.4 ()    Ports: 80/open/tcp//http//Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway|v2/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|https//Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway|v2/ Ignored State: filtered (4998)
Host: 5.5.5.5 (foobar.com)  Status: Up
Host: 5.5.5.5 (foobar.com)  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http?///, 443/open/tcp//ssl|https?///   Ignored State: filtered (4998)
Host: 6.6.6.6 ()    Status: Up
Host: 6.6.6.6 ()    Ports: 80/open/tcp//http//Microsoft IIS httpd 10.0/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//Microsoft IIS httpd 10.0/, 454/open/tcp//ssl|upnp//Microsoft IIS httpd/, 1221/open/tcp//http//Microsoft HTTPAPI httpd 2.0 (SSDP|UPnP)/, 4022/open/tcp//dnox?///, 4024/open/tcp//tnp1-port?///, 7654/open/tcp//unknown///   Ignored State: filtered (4993)
```

I'm trying to pull out all of the HTTP services while appending the port number (including services on port 1221, 454, and 443), but my attempts have failed:

```bsh
$ awk '/open/{print $2" "$5}' scan.gnmap | sed -e 's/\// /g' | awk '/http/{print $1":"$2}'

1.1.1.1:80
2.2.2.2:80
4.4.4.4:80
5.5.5.5:80
6.6.6.6:80
```

What is the simplest method for pulling out all of the HTTP host:port combinations?

Comment: Some of the grep/awk gurus here may be able to help, but my experience is that you will need to use something like Python/Perl/Tcl/etc to parse nmap output like this. The problem is that there may be zero or more matching _fields_ per line, and you would have to extract them one by one until no more are found, before proceeding to the next line.

Comment: awk '/Ports:/ && /http/ { print $2 }' lists all IP addresses with http. To also print the ports, use one of awk's string processing functions, looking for fields that start with a number followed by slash.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the expected output given that input so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible interpretation of your needs, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=":" }
{ ip = $2 }
sub(/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){3}Ports:[[:space:]]+/,"") {
    n = split($0,f,/\/[^,]+(,[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$)/)
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        port = f[i]
        if ( !seen[ip,port]++ ) {
            print ip, port
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1.1.1.1:80
1.1.1.1:443
2.2.2.2:80
2.2.2.2:443
3.3.3.3:25
4.4.4.4:80
4.4.4.4:443
5.5.5.5:80
5.5.5.5:443
6.6.6.6:80
6.6.6.6:443
6.6.6.6:454
6.6.6.6:1221
6.6.6.6:4022
6.6.6.6:4024
6.6.6.6:7654
```

If your awk doesn't support character classes and so isn't POSIX compliant, just change every `[[:space:]]` to `[ \t]` and `[^[:space:]]` to `[^ \t]`.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

while(<>) {
  next unless m/^Host: ([0-9.]+) .* Ports: (.*)(?:\s+Ignored.*)?/;
  # $1 and $2 are the values from the capture groups in the previous regex
  my ($ip, $ports) = ($1, $2);

  # split $ports into array @ports
  my @ports = split /,\s+/, $ports;

  # iterate over the array and output the IP and port number only when http appears
  foreach (@ports) {
    next unless s=^(\d+)\/.*http.*=$1=;
    printf "%s: %s\n", $ip, $_;
  };
}
```

Save as, e.g., `grep-http-ports.pl` and make executable with `chmod +x grep-http-ports.pl`.  Run like:

```
$ ./grep-http-ports.pl scan.gnmap 
1.1.1.1: 80
1.1.1.1: 443
2.2.2.2: 80
2.2.2.2: 443
4.4.4.4: 80
4.4.4.4: 443
5.5.5.5: 80
5.5.5.5: 443
6.6.6.6: 80
6.6.6.6: 443
6.6.6.6: 454
6.6.6.6: 1221
```

The spaces after the colons, `:` , are optional.  They make it more "human-readable", IMO. But if you don't like them or the output is intended for further processing with another script, just edit the `printf` format string to get rid of them.

---

If you want to extract the hostnames as well, that's easily done:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

while(<>) {
  next unless m/^Host: ([0-9.]+) \(([^)]*)\).* Ports: (.*)(?:\s+Ignored.*)?/;
  my ($ip, $host, $ports) = ($1, $2, $3);

  my @ports = split /,\s+/, $ports;

  foreach (@ports) {
    next unless s=^(\d+)\/.*http.*=$1=;
    printf "%s:%s:%s\n", $ip, $host, $_;
  };
}
```

```
1.1.1.1::80
1.1.1.1::443
2.2.2.2:foo.com:80
2.2.2.2:foo.com:443
4.4.4.4::80
4.4.4.4::443
5.5.5.5:foobar.com:80
5.5.5.5:foobar.com:443
6.6.6.6::80
6.6.6.6::443
6.6.6.6::454
6.6.6.6::1221
```

---

or with one line per IP address and port numbers separated by a comma and a space:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

while(<>) {
  next unless m/^Host: ([0-9.]+) .* Ports: (.*)(?:\s+Ignored.*)?/;
  my ($ip, $ports) = ($1, $2);

  next unless $ports =~ m/http/;
  my @ports = split /,\s+/, $ports;

  my @http = ();
  foreach (@ports) {
    next unless s=(\d+)\/.*http.*=$1=;
    push @http, $_;
  };

  printf "%s: %s\n", $ip, join(", ", @http);
}
```

```
$ ./grep-http-ports2.pl scan.gnmap 
1.1.1.1: 80, 443
2.2.2.2: 80, 443
4.4.4.4: 80, 443
5.5.5.5: 80, 443
6.6.6.6: 80, 443, 454, 1221
```

Again, the spaces after the colons and commas are optional.  Edit the `printf` format string and the `join` string as required.